# Como descobrir o endereço git de um repositorio já criado?

Tags: git, github

Comecei a trabalhar agora e a empresa usa o git para atualizar seu sistema, mas estou sozinho no departamento de ti como eu consigo o endereço desse repositorio já tentei pegar o msm endereço que utilizo para o git clone e aparece o seguinte erro

[image: segue o erro]

Comment: já tentou um `git remote -v` para ver pra onde está conectado o repositório?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar de duas maneiras para conseguir o endereço:

1. Executar comando abaixo:

```
$ git remote -v
```

2. Abre o arquivo de configuração no diretório `.git`:

```
$ cd .git
$ more config
```

Uma das duas soluções vai resolver seu problema.